# How to union two rdds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, rdd

now I have two rdds ,the first is  like this

1,2

3,4

5,6

and the other one is like this

7,8

9,10

11,12

now I want to union these two rdds like this

1,2,7,8

3,4,9,10

5,6,11,12

how can I do this? the rdd.union can't get this result

Comment: It would be better if you explain the `rdd` and paste some of your code here.

Answer (score 2):

If you can warranty that the two RDDs have the same number of elements and partitions, you can achieve the desired result with `rdd.zip`, and then re-shaping the resulting pairs:

```
rdd1.zip(rdd2).map{case ((a1,a2),(b1,b2))=> (a1,a2,b1,b2)}
```

If the two RDDs differ in the number of elements or partitions, you will need some key to join them. Indexing them is not very efficient but would serve the purpose, although a domain-specific solution (if existing) will be much better :

```
val indexed1 = rdd1.zipWithIndex.map(tuple => tuple.swap)
val indexed2 = rdd2.zipWithIndex.map(tuple => tuple.swap)

val joined = indexed1.join(indexed2)
val result = joined.map{case (k,((a1,a2),(b1,b2))) => (a1,a2,b1,b2)}
```